# Compare two columns, Clear duplicate cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare two columns (A and B) for duplicates. As an output I am trying to get cells that does not match (not duplicates). Column A values are coming from table 1 and Column B values are coming from table 2. Code target is basically to get to know which items were deleted from table 2 (Column B).

Data looks like:

```
A           B
BMW         PORSCHE
FIAT        VOLVO
VOLVO       AUDI
PORSCHE     FERRARI
FERRARI     TOYOTA
TOYOTA
AUDI
```

Output should be:

```
A           B
BMW
FIAT
```

This is working for highlighting duplicates, but how to get values deleted that are duplicates? For example using `.ClearContents`. Then after that I have loop for deleting empty rows in range.

```
Sub MarkDuplicatesInCompare()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim myrng As Range
    Dim clr As Long
    Dim lastCell As Range
    Dim EntireRow As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Compare")
    Set myrng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    With myrng
        Set lastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    myrng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    clr = 3

    For Each cell In myrng
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng, cell) > 1 Then

            If myrng.Find(what:=cell, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, after:=lastCell).Address = cell.Address Then

                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
                clr = clr
            Else

                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = myrng.Find(what:=cell, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, after:=lastCell).Interior.ColorIndex
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' Delete empty rows

    For I = myrng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set EntireRow = myrng.Cells(I, 1).EntireRow
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(EntireRow) = 0 Then
            EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If I understand it corretly, you want to delete values that are BOTH in column A and B ? So you are left with values in A that were NOT in B ?

Comment: @Vincent yes, basically I need to know what values were deleted from Column B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub Keanup()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, Na As Long, Nb As Long
    Na = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Nb = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = Na To 1 Step -1
        v = Cells(i, "A").Value
        For j = Nb To 1 Step -1
            If v = Cells(j, "B").Value Then
                Cells(i, "A").Delete shift:=xlUp
                Cells(j, "B").Delete shift:=xlUp
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note we run the loops **bottom up**.

Comment: Best practice should be have a `Worksheet` qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `AutoFilter()`

```
With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    .Rows(1).EntireRow.Insert ' insert temporary row for dummy headers
    With .Offset(-1).Resize(.Rows.Count + 1)
        .Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("h1", "h2") ' write dummy headers
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        .Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete ' remove dummy headers temporary row
    End With
End With
Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).ClearContents ' clear column B values
```

or with `Find()`

```
Dim cel As Range
With Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    For Each cel In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        If Not .Find(what:=cel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then cel.ClearContents
    Next
    .ClearContents
End With
```

which, should keeping "surivors" at the top be an issue, becomes:

```
Dim cel As Range, s As String
With Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    For Each cel In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        If Not .Find(what:=cel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then s = s & cel.Address(False, False) & " "
    Next
    .ClearContents
End With
If s <> vbNullString Then Range(Replace(Trim(s), " ", ",")).Delete xlUp
```